# Application compiled in mingw-w64/msys2, "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b"

Tags: c++, windows, msys, mingw-w64, msys2

After compiling an application in the `mingw-w64 64-bit Shell`, it runs fine inside the shell, but gives an error `the application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)` when run normally, outside the shell.

I moved some of the necessary DLLs from the msys2/mingw-w64 bin directories when it complained about missing them, but now it gives this opaque error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Error `0xc00007b` basically means "invalid image format" which usually happens when mixing 64-bit and 32-bit DLLs. What is happening, is that you have a 64-bit application, looking for a particular DLL, which *is* in the global path, but the one in the path is 32-bit. Therefore, the problem is: it does not complain about the missing DLL, it just tries to load it. Since it is a 32-bit application, and your application is a 64-bit application, you get error `0xc00007b`.

The solution is to copy *all* the dependent DLLs over to the application path.

The next problem is you don't know which ones.

What you can do with msys2 shell is: go to the directory and run the command:

```
ldd application.exe
```

This will give you a list of DLLs the application depends on. Copy the msys2/mingw-w64 related DLLs to the directory. This will allow the application to find them before looking in the PATH and finding the 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) displays all dependencies, that are linked using compile-time dynamic linking. Similar to your suggest approach to use `ldd` it will not account for dependencies that are linked using runtime dynamic linking (Dependency Walker allows you to profile your application, so you might catch some of them this way).

Comment: @IInspectable sure, I am aware of dependency walker. It's a great tool. Haven't used it in years. `ldd` is part of mingw-w64 so i found it useful to use that.

Comment: Thanks for the useful thread. Not sure yet whether it's causing my problem, but it's valuable either way. Since it might be related: (A) Can this occur when conversely running a 32-bit cross-compiled program on a 64-bit OS, and (B) Do you know why, whereas running from Explorer or Command Prompt gives this error - when running from the same MSYS2-supplied `mingw32` shell, the program simply exits immediately with no apparent error?

Comment: Unfortunately at least in my case ldd reported "a few" dependencies, including some rather unuseful ones like `??? => ??? (0xd0000)` whereas dependency walker showed me the ones that were actually missing :|

Comment: "copy all the dependent DLLs", in my case ldd is showing dependency on both `/c/Windows/System32/ntdll.dll` and `/c/Windows/SysWow64/ntdll.dll`, tried both, none work